# INotifyPropertyChanged is not working, data binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I am adding some data in listbox and using Inotifypropertychanged to notify,
Its very simple code but its not working, after clicking button data in listbox does not change

My xaml

> ```
> <Grid>
>     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
>         <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" Width=" 250" ItemsSource="{Binding listoffiles}" >
>
>         </ListBox>
>         <Button x:Name="btntest" Width=" 50" Height=" 20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin=" 10" Content=" Test it"></Button>
>         <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" Height=" 50" Width=" 100"  Margin="0,135" Text="{Binding text}"/>
>     </StackPanel>
> </Grid> </Window>
> ```

My viewmodiel class

```
> `Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel Imports System.ComponentModel`
> 
> 

    Public Class testdata
    >     Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

> 
>     Public Property listoffiles As List(Of String)
>         Get
>             Return _listoffiles
>         End Get
>         Set(value As List(Of String))
>             _listoffiles = value
>             onpropertchange("listoffiles")
>         End Set
>     End Property
> 
>     Public Property text As String
>         Get
>             Return _text
>         End Get
>         Set(value As String)
>             _text = value
>             onpropertchange("text")
>         End Set
>     End Property
> 
> 
>     Private _listoffiles As New List(Of String)
>     Private _text As String
> 
>     Public Sub New()
>         _listoffiles.Add("One")
>         _listoffiles.Add("One")
>         _listoffiles.Add("One")
>         
>     End Sub
> 
>     Protected Sub onpropertchange(name As String)
>         RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
>     End Sub
> 
>     Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged End Class

My view.vb

> Class MainWindow
>    
> 
>     Private Property viewmodel As testdata = New testdata
>     Private Sub btntest_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btntest.Click
>         viewmodel.listoffiles.Add("two")
>         viewmodel.listoffiles.Add("two")
>         viewmodel.listoffiles.Add("two")
>         viewmodel.listoffiles.Add("two")
>         viewmodel.listoffiles.Add("two")
>         
> 
>         Dim listoffiles As List(Of String) = viewmodel.listoffiles
>     End Sub End Cla
```

ss

Comment: check out the edit I made to my post

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `List` to be an `ObservableCollection`.  `ObservableCollection` has an event called `NotifyCollectionChanged`.  This event is raised when calling methods such as `Add()`, `Remove()`, etc that updates the collection.

So you need to make the following code changes for this to work

1. change the `listoffiles` to a public property
2. set the `datacontext` in the constructor of `MainWindow`
3. set the `listoffiles` to equal `viewmodel.listoffiles` in constructor of `MainWindow`

below is a working version of the code you posted above

```
Class MainWindow

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    DataContext = Me
    listoffiles = viewmodel.listoffiles
End Sub
Private Property viewmodel As testdata = New testdata
Public Property listoffiles As New ObservableCollection(Of String)

Private Sub btntest_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles bnttest.Click
    viewmodel.listoffiles.Add("two")
    viewmodel.listoffiles.Add("two")
    viewmodel.listoffiles.Add("two")
    viewmodel.listoffiles.Add("two")
    viewmodel.listoffiles.Add("two")
End Sub
End Class



Public Class testdata
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged


Public Property listoffiles As ObservableCollection(Of String)
    Get
        Return _listoffiles
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of String))
        _listoffiles = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property text As String
    Get
        Return _text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _text = value

    End Set
End Property


Private _listoffiles As New ObservableCollection(Of String)
Private _text As String

Public Sub New()
    _listoffiles.Add("One")
    _listoffiles.Add("One")
    _listoffiles.Add("One")
End Sub

Protected Sub onpropertchange(name As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
End Sub

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

Comment: Tried doing that... but still same when I click button data in listbox does not change.

Comment: Have you used Inotifypropertychanged in above code? can you post your xaml? still its not working!!

Comment: xaml is the same.  However, I did use a different name for the button.  I changed the name back to what you used but forgot to change the click event.  I edited my post so if you copy in the code it should work.  Just make sure the name of the click event corresponds to your button

Comment: And I did not use `INotifyPropertyChanged` because all I cared about was the collection.  You only use INotifyProperetyChanged` for property that is not a collection.  If the property is a collection you need to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` or you can just use the `ObservableCollection` which already implements it.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your binding as follows...

```
ItemsSource="{Binding listoffiles, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Your binding probably works correctly for the initial pass, but it's not staying updated with the property.

Comment: Still its not working. seems to be straight forward  but its so frustrating.. It is not working!!!! Working in initialization though, it displays default data